# How to draw text in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, freetype

I'm trying to draw text with OpenGL, but it doesn't display right, or even consistently. From what I gather, it is in the creation or binding of the bitmap that doesn't work. I'll admit that I don't fully understand the FT_Load_Char method or the glTexImage2D method, so it's likely that one of those methods is the issue.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H

void drawText(char* text, FT_Face face)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (*(text + i) != '\0')
    {
        auto error = FT_Load_Char( face, text[i], FT_LOAD_RENDER );
        if (!error)
        {
            FT_GlyphSlot glyphSlot = face->glyph;
            FT_Bitmap bitmap = face->glyph->bitmap;
            unsigned char* buffer = face->glyph->bitmap.buffer;

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
            glColor3f (1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            glBegin (GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f (0,0);
            glVertex2d (-0.9375 + 0.25*(i%8), 0.9375 - .25*(i/8));
            glTexCoord2f (0,1);
            glVertex2d (-0.9375 + 0.25*(i%8), 0.8125 - .25*(i/8));
            glTexCoord2f (1,1);
            glVertex2d (-0.8125 + 0.25*(i%8), 0.8125 - .25*(i/8));
            glTexCoord2f (1,0);
            glVertex2d (-0.8125 + 0.25*(i%8), 0.9375 - .25*(i/8));
            glEnd ();
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::Window App(sf::VideoMode(500, 500, 32), "Text Test");

    // Set color and depth clear value
    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    glEnable (GL_BLEND);
    glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    FT_Library library;
    FT_Face face;

    auto error = FT_Init_FreeType( &library );
    if ( error )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    error = FT_New_Face( library,
                       "arial.ttf",
                       0,
                       &face );
    if ( error == FT_Err_Unknown_File_Format )
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if ( error )
    {
        return 3;
    }

    error = FT_Set_Char_Size(
            face,    /* handle to face object           */
            0,       /* char_width in 1/64th of points  */
            16*64,   /* char_height in 1/64th of points */
            300,     /* horizontal device resolution    */
            300 );   /* vertical device resolution      */
            if ( error )
    {
        return 4;
    }

    char * text = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";

    // Start game loop
    while (App.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            // Close window : exit
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                App.close();

            if ((Event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed))
            {
                if (Event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)// Escape key : exit
                {
                    App.close();
                }
            }
        }
        glPopMatrix();

        // Clear color and depth buffer
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        drawText(text, face);
        glPushMatrix();

        // Finally, display rendered frame on screen
        App.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I run this, this is the result:
[image: broken text]

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to fix my problem?

Comment: Some of that (possibly all of it) is due to alignment. Have you tried using `glPixelStorei (GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)`? The default value is **4** byte alignment, and that's not what you want for a monochrome 8-bit image.

Comment: and you are using the deprecated API

Comment: If you want to learn how to use OpenGL, learn modern OpenGL, the legacy stuff is really not worth learning in detail. If you don't want to learn OpenGL, why don't you just use SFML's text rendering?